# ASP.NET How to save and use persistent information depending on user type login

Tags: asp.net

I´m building a website and i need to store somehow some informations that i will use in the whole site depending of the user type logged in.

Example:

1) User XPTO logs in

2) Query DataBase to see where he belongs

3) Store those 2 or 3 fields that i will get in Database in a persistent way to use it in the whole site.

My question is: Whats the best practices to do this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Session**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) for storing session specific information.

Comment: Anyone wants to give other opinion?

Comment: Session is intended to be used for this purpose.